# Android Build Your First App

Tags: java, android

recently I started Build Your First App on Android Developer's Website. However, I accidentally deleted every import thing. So does anyone have the code to all of the import command things? Thank you.

Comment: We know nothing of the site or the code you lost.  If you could track down the site, I'm sure that they'd have a way for you to recover the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio, and you delete the imports in a java class, the objects that use that import will turn red. If you place your mouse over the red objects in the code and press alt + enter, Android Studio will auto import the needed class.

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1: USE IMPORT SHORTCUT**

You can use the shortcut `CTRL + ALT + O` to Optimize all imports.

or you can use your own custom shortcut by going to `File -> Settings -> KeyMap`

**OPTION 2: AUTO IMPORT**

Goto `File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import -> Java` and make the following changes:

change `Insert imports on paste` value to `All`

mark `Add unambigious imports on the fly` option as `checked`

**OPTION 3: MANUALLY IMPORT ONE BY ONE**

Place your mouse cursor on the error objects and press `Alt + Enter` to import the file.